# Can I run 12/2 low voltage wire for landscape lighting through a crawl space?

Tags: lighting, low-voltage, landscape

Question re: low voltage landscape lighting wiring. If the 300 watt transformers are mounted in a garage or dry crawl space, can I run the 12/2 direct burial wire through the crawl space/garage to the outside?  I’m pretty sure when the wire goes through the wall it must be through conduit. What I’m unclear about is what kind of wire must I use to go from the transformer through the conduit. Can it be the same direct burial wire?  Or just it be something else since it’s inside the home?  I’m getting different opinions.

---

Actually 18 AWG would be far from sufficient.  I'm looking at 12 AWG and, more likely, 10 AWG for one run that is 150' long carrying a load of 150 watts.

I'm glad to hear you all say that 12/2 or 10/2 direct burial wire can be used within the garage and crawl space.  On another board, others were suggesting that it had to be another rated wire until it got outside.  There it would have to connect with the direct burial in a junction box of sorts.  Glad I don't have to do that!

But I am curious.  I don't do soffit lighting, but LV soffit lighting can run off the same system as a home's outdoor landscape lighting.  It's common practice that soffit lighting wire CANNOT be the same 12/2 direct burial wire.  Rather, it must be CL2 rated.  Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "low voltage"?

Comment: What is the designation on the wire you are planning to use?

Comment: Why are you spending the money on 12/2 for low voltage lighting? Relative to need, that's pretty expensive stuff these days. Also, please ask a new question about the soffit lighting. With that there, this is bordering on being too broad and might get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from the "networking" side of low voltage wiring, you are (under NEC rules, anyway - presumably applicable since you are not specifying wire sizes by mm<sup>2</sup>) limited to 50 feet or less inside the building for cable that is not rated for indoor use.

It's NOT "low voltage - no rules!" as some folks like to think.

This has to do with the flammability and smoke produced from the wire insulation. It's possible to source "Indoor/outdoor" rated wires/cables, (which are not subject to the limit, since they are indoor rated) or you can locate a junction box (or the transformer) less than 50 feet of wire run from the wall penetration. Running in conduit can extend that distance, when needed, since the conduit keeps the non-rated insulation out of direct fire/flame contact inside.

However, as **a practical matter** you will be better off putting the transformer *as close to the wall penetration as possible,* since voltage drop from the supply to the transformer (at 120 or 240VAC) will be much, much less than voltage drop from the transformer to the lights, (at 10, 12, 16, 24, or possibly 32 VAC) for the same length of cable. And, given a large load on a long run planned, you should consider using a higher voltage that still qualifies as low voltage, for less resistive losses (i.e. 24V rather than 12V - twice the voltage, half the current, one quarter the voltage drop.)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are talking about 12volts as low-voltage.  You can use the same wire inside, because it is low voltage.

If you have a gap through the wall, like a vent or under, you can just track it through there.